# how to fetch data in single array instead of arrays of arrays

Tags: php

Controller:

```
$student = $this->school_model->get_school_students($institute);    
echo "<pre>";    
print_r($student);    
echo implode(',',$student);    
exit;
```

Model:

```
function get_school_students($institute=''){    
    $query=$this->db->query("SELECT id FROM users as u where     
    u.current_educational_institution = '$institute' and u.deleted=0 AND     u.role=2");    
    $result=$query->result_array();    
    if($query->num_rows()>0){     
        // $output=array();    
        $output=$result;    
    }    
    return $output;    
}
```

Output:

```
Array    
(    
    [0] => Array    
        (    
            [id] => 280    
        )    

    [1] => Array    
        (    
            [id] => 282    
        )    
)    

Array,Array ......
```

I want to echo 280,282 from implode but it is showing array array??? help me?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

***Reason:-*** Data that you are getting from function is multi-dimensional-array and [implode()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.implode.php) works on single-dimensional-array .That's why you are facing problem.

***Solution:-***

convert your multi-dimensional-array to single-dimensional-array using `array_colum()`like below:-

```
echo implode(',',array_column($student,'id'));
```

Output:-https://eval.in/829544

Reference:- [array_column()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-column.php)